Почему к кнопке в Android не применяются стили?
Пишу приложение на Android, использую Java.
У меня есть 2 кнопки на странице:

1-я начинает поиск устройств рядом
2-я отключается от устройства, к которому подключен телефон.

Делаю стилизацию кнопок, и возникла проблема: 1-я кнопка хорошо работает, все стили на ней видны, а вот со 2-й возникли проблемы.
Вот так выглядит экран приложения:

2-я кнопка должна быть красной и должна сохранить свою форму.
Вот разметка первой кнопки, с которой всё хорошо:
<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
    style="@style/text"
    android:layout_width="228dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/standart_button"
    android:backgroundTint="@null"
    android:onClick="searchDevicesClickButton"
    android:text="@string/search"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

Вот xml-разметка второй кнопки:
<Button
    android:id="@+id/closeConnectionButton"
    style="@style/text"
    android:layout_width="228dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/close_button"
    android:onClick="searchDevicesClickButton"
    android:text="@string/turn_off_bluetooth_connection"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

Вот стиль text:
<style name="text">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/montserrat_medium</item>
</style>

Вот background второй кнопки:
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="228dp"
    android:height="42dp"
    android:viewportWidth="228"
    android:viewportHeight="42">
  <path
      android:pathData="M10,0L217,0A10,10 0,0 1,227 10L227,32A10,10 0,0 1,217 42L10,42A10,10 0,0 1,0 32L0,10A10,10 0,0 1,10 0z"
      android:fillColor="@color/red"/>
</vector>

Выглядит он так:


И вот самое интересное: по какой-то причине сама вторая кнопка окрашена не в красный!
Вот скриншот с телефона, когда я запускаю приложение:

Как это можно исправить?

На второй нет android:backgroundTint

@Style-7 к сожалению его добавление ничего не меняет. Даже если выставляю ему значение @color/red или @null.

 Это?

Вероятно, дело в том, что стиль кнопке в части цвета фона надо более сложным способом задавать. У вас, вероятно, кнопке програмно enabled свойство задаётся и потому вы на девайсе другой цвет видите. Если вы просто Button на TextView замените - фон должен заработать. А чтобы с кнопкой заработало - надо, наверное, через StateList фон прописывать как-то

@ЮрийСПб enabled не влияет на фон в данном случае.

Скорее всего у вас material theme, поэтому там инфлейтится MaterialButton под капотом, а оно игнорирует android:background если не добавить app:backgroundTint="@null" (именно с app:), но это скорее "хак".
Лучше не использовать android:background для MaterialButton, а использовать app:cornerRadius (либо app:shapeAppearance) для нужного закругления углов и app:backgroundTint для смены цвета кнопки.
